# Android save FileOutputStream in gallery

Tags: java, android, image, gallery, fileoutputstream

I have an image created with `FileOutputStream` and I try to save it to gallery. I was looking for stack overflow answers and everywhere else and nothing works for me

My code:

```
File path = MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir("ComputerScreenshots");
FileOutputStream ops = new FileOutputStream(path + "/Computer.png");
```

The code above saves the image in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.computer/files/ComputerScreenshots/Computer.png`

How can I save it to gallery?

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Not so. But not terrible. I will try other ways thank you very much mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below code will help you.

```
File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "ComputerScreenshots");
```

Check your directory is existing or not? if not then make it.

```
if (!path.exists())
        path.mkdir()
```

If you want to save your Image into Camera Directory then Replace **ComputerScreenshots** to **Camera**

Comment: wait i'll send it

Comment: ```java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ComputerScreenshots/Computer.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)```

Comment: I changed to ```Camera``` and I got ```java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Computer.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)```

Comment: Do you have Directory created?

Comment: No, that's why I tried to save on camera and access was denied

Comment: I want to save it in camera. And I got an access when I added ```android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"```

Comment: But now I don't find the image in the camera Directory

Comment: Are you running runtime permission?

Comment: Now I got permission. But I have new issue. I can save the image. It works, but when I open the gallery, I don't find the image' only when I connect the phone to the computer, I find it it the gallery (from the explorer)

Comment: Why can I find the image only through the computer in the cell phone file explorer?

Comment: `if (!path.exists())
        path.mkdir()` Check if it is created: `if (!path.exists())
      if ( !path.mkdir()){ Toast(..sorry could not create directory...); return;}` The discussion is about not being able to create a file. But the directory cannot be created to begin with. Know your problem!